# M-N relation without joint entity not present in .NET Core 3 EF and no docs on why

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

From .NET Core 3, it was [implied](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration#note) (old article mentions *at least from version 3* and it's been discussed in other blogs too) that the necessity of a joint entity between *A* and *B* that manages the M-N relation, would be removed.

However, I can't seem to get it to work at the moment. Checking [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) and [new features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/), it seems that the feature **still** hasn't been induced.

Am I missing the feature doing it wrong or is it the case that it still not introduced in EF Core 3? If so, where is any documentation about it? I haven't found any articles confirming *oops, sorry, ain't happening yet*.

It is a fundamentally important feature and it's already implemented since long time in EF for .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 'Postponed features' section of the EF Core release notes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#postponed-features) (which you kindly provided) it references issue [9914 - Shared-type entities (part of property bag entities)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9914) which is mentioned as part of issue [10508 - Implement many-to-many relationships without mapping join table](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10508) with the following comment:

> Current plan for 3.0 is to implement skip-level navigation properties as a stretch goal. If property bags (#9914) also make it into 3.0, enabling a seamless experience for many-to-many could become easier.

So it looks like it didn't make it, but you can at least track your interest on the issues

Answer (score 1):

Well from the [Relationship Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns) it seems like it is not implemented yet.

> Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

If you have a look to [aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore #10508](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10508#issuecomment-389922109) It is still an open issiue that it is not planned for 3.0

> Current plan for <del>3.0</del> is to implement skip-level navigation properties as a stretch goal. If property bags (#9914) also make it into <del>3.0</del>, enabling a seamless experience for many-to-many could become easier. - divega

It is also [not planned for 5.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/milestone/70) so I assume we have to wait for it.